# Asynchronous Process in Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous

I'd like to wait requests 10 secs per each request but requests don't must wait each other.so second request doesn't must wait 20 seconds.

**My Servlet:**

```
    @WebServlet(value = "/account", asyncSupported = true)
    public class AccountServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {

        public AccountServlet() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            AsyncContext ac = request.startAsync();

            ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(10);
            executor.execute(new MyAsyncService(ac));
        }

        @Override
        public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

        }
    }
```

**My asynchronous process class:**

```
    class MyAsyncService implements Runnable {

        AsyncContext ac;

        public MyAsyncService(AsyncContext ac) {
            this.ac = ac;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("started");
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                System.out.println("completed");
                ac.complete();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MyAsyncService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be more optimal to schedule the completion of the request without blocking a thread. Below is your code modified to do that (using Java 8 lambdas).

```
@WebServlet(value = "/account", asyncSupported = true)
public class AccountServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        AsyncContext ac = request.startAsync();
        executor.schedule(ac::complete, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Note that depending on your runtime environment (i.e. container) you might not be allowed to create your own executor and might need to use one provided by EE container.

Comment: i tested this.when i open new tab in the same browser each tab waits for eachother.i mean second tab is waiting 20 seconds instead of 10 sec.but when i test in other browsers each browser wait 10 seconds doesn't wait for eachother.Your code reacts same as my code

Comment: Are you sure there is no other logic applied? For example filter which adds a delay? Don't you call also your `MyAsyncService` instead of just scheduling the task in the executor? You might add some logging before `executor.schedule` and inside the lambda (instead of just invoking ac::complete) and see when those statements are printed.

Comment: i opened the new application and just add one servlet into app and paste your code.so result is each tab is waiting for each other.Did you test your code?

Comment: It was working using curl. Now I checked it from browser and it seems the browser detects that you call the same URL and waits with issuing new requests for the same URL (I am using Chrome). What's interesting when I open developer console in each tab and open those URLs there, Chrome doesn't wait but issues HTTP requests immediately.
Check with developer mode opened in each tab or invoke my sample code using curl or call it from browser but append a unique query in each tab (e.g. /account?foo, /account?bar etc.) to check if it's working.